# android horizontal listview

Tags: android, listview, binary-tree

I'm currently doing a hierarchical tree structure.
For that, I am using a horizontal ListView.

Inside the horizontal ListView I am using an ImageButton.
On top I have 1 ImageButton, below 2 ImageButtons, under that 4 ImageButtons, under that 8 ImageButtons.

Any image on the top ImageButtons should be changed dynamically.

This is my code.

```
public class HorizontalListViewDemo extends Activity {
    private AdapterMain mAdapter;
    ImageButton ib1,ib2;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


  HorizontialListView listview = (HorizontialListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
  mAdapter = new AdapterMain(this);
  listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);



      listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                  long id) {


              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"pos:"+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

public class AdapterMain extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context mContext;

public AdapterMain(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.listviewdemo, null);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

my base adapter class